# Working with a custom ListUpdateCallback and PagedList out of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm using

```
android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-rc1
android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-rc1
```

to retrieve a PagedList through LiveData from a DataSource built by a simple select (`SELECT * FROM data where isOn = 1`)

This DataSource is observed and submits its PagedList to following custom adapter dedicated to update a drawer with current "isOn" list:

```
data class Data(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
                    var id: Int = 0,
                    var name: String? = null,
                    var isOn: Boolean? = null)

class ApiDrawerAdapter(drawer: Drawer) {

    private val lastItemPositionOffset = drawer.drawerItems.size

    val drawerItems = arrayListOf<PrimaryDrawerItem>()

    private val listUpdateCallback = object : ListUpdateCallback {
        override fun onChanged(position: Int, count: Int, payload: Any?) {
            for (i in position until position + count) {
                val name = getItem(i)?.name ?: "Unnamed data"
                val primaryDrawerItemOpt: PrimaryDrawerItem? = drawerItems.getOrNull(i)
                primaryDrawerItemOpt?.let { pdi -> drawerItems.remove(pdi) }
                primaryDrawerItemOpt?.identifier?.let { id -> drawer.removeItem(id) }
                val primaryDrawerItem = (primaryDrawerItemOpt ?: PrimaryDrawerItem()).withName(name)
                drawer.setItemAtPosition(primaryDrawerItem, i + lastItemPositionOffset)
                drawerItems.set(i, primaryDrawerItem)
            }
        }

        override fun onMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
            throw Exception("Not implemented")
        }

        override fun onInserted(position: Int, count: Int) {
                for (i in position until position + count) {
                    val name = getItem(i)?.name ?: "Unnamed data"
                    val primaryDrawerItem = PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(name)
                    drawer.setItemAtPosition(primaryDrawerItem, i + lastItemPositionOffset)
                    drawerItems.add(i, primaryDrawerItem)
                }
        }

        override fun onRemoved(position: Int, count: Int) {
            for (i in position until position + count) {
                val primaryDrawerItemOpt: PrimaryDrawerItem? = drawerItems.getOrNull(position)
                primaryDrawerItemOpt?.let { pdi -> drawerItems.remove(pdi) }
                primaryDrawerItemOpt?.identifier?.let { id -> drawer.removeItem(id) }
            }
        }
    }

    private val itemCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Data> = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Data>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Data, newItem: Data): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Data, newItem: Data): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
    private val asyncDifferConfig = AsyncDifferConfig.Builder<Data>(itemCallback).build()

    private val mDiffer = AsyncPagedListDiffer(listUpdateCallback, asyncDifferConfig)

    init {
        val mListener = AsyncPagedListDiffer.PagedListListener<Data> { }

        mDiffer.mListener = mListener
    }

    fun submitList(pagedList: PagedList<Data>) {

        mDiffer.submitList(pagedList)
    }

    protected fun getItem(position: Int): Data? {
        return mDiffer.getItem(position)
    }

}
```

It works well in most cases but I couldn't figure a specific case:
When I have

```
1 - A
2 - B
3 - C
4 - D
5 - E
6 - F
```

Let's say that my current state (the one with isOn at true) is:

```
2 - B
3 - C
4 - D
```

I'm changing the state to:

```
1 - A
4 - D
5 - E
```

Doing so, the custom receives ListUpdateCallback (I'm catching errors at this point):

```
I/onInserted: position 3 and count 1
I/onRemoved: position 0 and count 2
I/onInserted: position 0 and count 1
```

The logic should probably do:

```
Insert E at offset 3
Delete 2 items (B C) at offset 0
Insert A at offset 0
```

As you can see the call parameters are matching that logic.
However getItem that iterate into the PagedStorage instance that is backing the AsyncPagedListDiffer.getItem relies on the expected list:

```
1 - A
4 - D
5 - E
```

Therefore getItem(3) will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

So my issue is: how do I know that I need to add the item 2 to the position 3 in this case?
I think I'm missing something but I don't know if it's a design issue or that I made an error in my insertion logic.
I tried to look into RecyclerView code that appears to manage that case but it's so long to review that I'm asking here if someone managed to get it done or know if it can get done that way (or another).